# How to get the real value of a VALUE socket in python?

Tags: python, scripting, shader-nodes

As the title says, I need to get the actual value of a `VALUE` socket (not `vector`, `RGB` or `shader`).
I know how to get the `default_value`, but I need the real one. I've searched around and I've seen a lot of people asking similar questions, but for different types of more complicated sockets. So I'd like to understand if this is possible at least for the basic `VALUE` socket.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with default_value?

Comment: What do you want to do? How it expected to have a singular value if textures or dynamic values can be plugged in?

Comment: `default_value` is the value of the socket when nothing is plugged into it, it is indeed the value that's displayed in the field

Comment: Ah, my bad... I misunderstood the `default_value` behaviour, thinkin that it was just the value set during the node creation, and not the one displayed in the field... Now everything is working fine, and I'm sorry for the dumb question... I started coding in the Blender environment less then a week ago, so I'm still learning.

Comment: @user2959923 It's not a dumb question.  We've all wondered about default_value at some point.  Blender's bpy interface is not the most intuitive one ever designed.

Comment: Yes it is misleading, and no it isn't a dumb question ! The `default_value` has a default value which defines its value on node creation, but its value can be changed at runtime. You can't change it's default value at runtime though. ><